# Support Vector Machine on Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, machine-learning

Is there is an implementation of Support Vector Machine on Hadoop ?
I am looking for a code that lets me train and then test the SVM Model on top of Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody is working on an implementation on top of [Apache Hama](http://hama.apache.org/) with BSP, which is basically a port of the MPI version of this project:
http://code.google.com/p/psvm/

You can track his progress here:

https://github.com/truncs/hello-world

https://github.com/truncs/psvm

I guess it will take 1-2 months to finish it, the main part is actually running.